# POO PHP - Undefined index: user y password

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined index: user in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DSagredo\inc\functions.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DSagredo\inc\functions.php on line 19

**INDEX.PHP**

```
$obj->getLogueo();  

if (isset($_GET["m"]) && !empty($_GET["m"])) 
{
    $error_msg = "<div class='error'>Usuario o contraseña incorrectos</div>";
}

include 'inc/header.php';
?>
<div class="caja">

    <div class="foro">
        <form method="post" action="#">
        <?php echo $error_msg; ?>
        <h2>Iniciar sesión</h2>
        <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        <br>
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Entrar</button>
      </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

**FUNCTION.PHP**

```
public function getLogueo() 
   {
      $user = $_POST["user"];
      $pass = md5($_POST["password"]);

      $res = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT id, name, kind from user where user = '$user' and password = '$pass'");

      while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) 
      {
         $this->login[] = $row;
      }

      if (sizeof($this->login) > 0) 
      {
         foreach ($this->login as $key) 
         {
            $_SESSION["id"] = $key["id"];
            $_SESSION["name"] = $key["name"];
            $_SESSION["kind"] = $key["kind"];
            switch ($_SESSION["kind"]) 
            {
               case 1: header("Location: panel.php");
               break;
               case 2: header("Location: index2.php");
               break;
            }
         }
      } else {
         header("Location: index.php?m=1");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Hola Diego, ¿podrías mostrarnos el código de link.class.php?

Comment: Hola Juan Pinzón, me equivoque , link,class.php cambia el nombre por function,php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si llamas los elementos de la variable `$_POST` antes de enviar cualquier form a traves de POST, esos indices en el arreglo no estarán disponibles.

Estas llamando la función getLogueo al inicio

```
$obj->getLogueo();
```

La cual tiene:

```
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = md5($_POST["password"]);
```

Por lo que si abres la página que llama esa función, estos elementos no estarán disponibles.

Para corregirlo podrías usara la funcion `isset()` para comprobar que están seteados correctamente, podrías hacer algo así.

```
public function getLogueo() {
  if(isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $user = $_POST["user"];
    $pass = md5($_POST["password"]);

    $res = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT id, name, kind from user where user = '$user' and password = '$pass'");

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
      $this->login[] = $row;
    }

    if (sizeof($this->login) > 0) {
      foreach ($this->login as $key) {
        $_SESSION["id"] = $key["id"];
        $_SESSION["name"] = $key["name"];
        $_SESSION["kind"] = $key["kind"];
        switch ($_SESSION["kind"]) {
           case 1: header("Location: panel.php");
           break;
           case 2: header("Location: index2.php");
           break;
        }
      }
    } else {
     header("Location: index.php?m=1");
    }
  }else{
    echo "No se ha enviado nada por post";
  }
}
```

Comment: Si funciona bien, muy buena tu comentario. Gracias compare.

Comment: Juan Pinzon pero te pido , hay una problema , 
Notice: Undefined variable: error_msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\DSagredo\index.php on line 18

Comment: Es lo mismo, estas llamando `error_msg` antes de que este seteado, utiliza isset() para controlarlo, `if(isset($error_msg)){ echo $error_msg; }`

Comment: entendido, un excelente. Gracias